# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and RTL8125 on MSI MAG B550 tomahawk

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have installed Kubuntu 20.04 on my new PC based on MSI MAG B550 tomahawk motherboard. The motherboard has two Ethernet ports: one is gigabit and another is 2.5 gigabit. Gigabit port works, but 2.5 gigabit one not working.

Here's the output of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
   logical name: enp40s0
   version: 15
   serial: 2c:f0:5d:3e:a3:04
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:37 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc604000-fc604fff memory:fc600000-fc603fff
   *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:2a:00.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc50ffff memory:fc510000-fc513fff
```

The system is running `5.4.0-42-generic` kernel. I have tried to install `r8168-dkms` package but got the same results as listed above. Windows 10 successfully runs both Ethernet adapters.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've faced same issue too. The driver update may come soon, because The rtl8125b support has been added to the linux-next tree July 14. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek?h=next-20200720&id=0439297be95111cf9ef5ece2091af16d140ce2ef